# How can I bring over more than one column in this lookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to compare two files: new data and old data. I place the new data in a ws and then do a lookup to data from the old file to indicate that it's preexisting. Currently, my lookup values exist in 4 consecutive columns: H:K. right now, I am only able to get the lookup values from column H in my source sheet, how can I add another loop to go through the other three columns?

EDIT:another way to put it would be: I want `Then .add Cl.Value, Cl.Offset(,1).Resize(,7:10)`, but I know I can't actually code it like that. Every time I add in the cell value in column A, I also want it to store columns H, I, J, K in that row, but it now only does column H.

code:

```
Dim Cl As Range
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim extWS As Worksheet, tgtWS As Worksheet

Set tgtWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Longer Than 9 Months")
Set Wbk = workbooks("external.xlsx")
Set extWS = Wbk.Sheets("Longer Than 9 Months")

With CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Cl In extWS.Range("A2", extWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .Exists(Cl.Value) Then .Add Cl.Value, Cl.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 7)
    Next Cl
    For Each Cl In tgtWS.Range("A2", tgtWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If .Exists(Cl.Value) Then Cl.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 7).Value = .Item(Cl.Value).Value
    Next Cl
End With
```

Comment: Why not `Offset(,7).Resize(,4)` or do you also need B:G?

Comment: actually figured out a solution, but this also solves it!